# Groups of order $16$ with a cyclic quotient of order $4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

**Question**: I am interested in

(a) listing the groups $G$ of order $16$ which have a cyclic quotient of order $4$;

(b) in each case knowing in how many essentially different ways this occurs (identifying cases where the kernels are in the same orbit under $\mathop{Aut}(G)$).

---

**My working** (edited after Derek Holt pointed out a silly mistake:

(A) Of the $14$ groups of order $16$ there are five abelian ones,
of which four namely

$\mathbb{Z}_{16}$,

$\mathbb{Z}_8\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$,

$\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$,

$\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$

have such a quotient. It seems to me that in each case we get only one such quotient.

(B) A non-abelian group $G$ of order $16$ can only have such a quotient if its derived group $G'$ has order $2$ and $G/G'\simeq\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Inspecting the list at https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16
it *seems to me* that the only possibilities are

SmallGroup(16,3),

the non-trivial semi-direct product of Z4 and Z4,

the group M16

I  am not sure about the uniqueness of the quotients.

Comment: Six of the fourteen groups of order $16$ have derived groups of order $2$, but they do not include $D_{16}$, ${\rm SD}_{16}$ and $Q_{16}$, which all have derived groups of order $4$.

Comment: I have edited my workings to deal with @DerekHolt 's comment.

Comment: @DerekHolt. Obviously I must be miscalculating. I thought that in $G=D_8\times C_2$ we have $G'=\Phi(G)\simeq C_2$, and so there are no cyclic quotients of order $4$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right and what I wrote was nonsense. The three groups that you listed are indeed the only nonabelian example with cyclic quotients of order $4$. For some reason I was just looking at the groups with derived group of order $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered your question about uniqueness using computer calculations.

For the first two nonabelian example, $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(16,3)$ and $C_4 \rtimes C_4$, there are two normal subgroups with quotient $C_4$, but in both cases there is an automorphism of the group mapping one to the other, do they are (essentially) unique.

In the third example $M_{16}$, however, there are again two normal subgroups with quotient $C_4$, but this time all group automorphisms fix both subgroups, so the  two subgroups are essentially distinct.

$M_{16}$ can be defined by the presentation $\langle x,y \mid x^8=y^2=1, y^{-1}xy=x^5 \rangle$, and the two normal subgroups are $\langle x^4,y \rangle$ and $\langle x^4,yx^2 \rangle$.In fact these two subgroups are not even isomorphic: the second one is cyclic but the first one not.

Comment: Thank you Derek, tomorrow after I have done a bit of work I will ask about the classes of normal subgroups of index 2 ;-)