# Groups of order $16$ and their subgroups of index $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

**Question**: For each of the groups $P$ of order 16 determine the classes of subgroups of index $2$ under the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(P)$.

**Context**: For almost $60$ years it has seemed to me that on their $N$-th birthday group theorists ought to classify (or at least know something about) the groups of order $N$. After a long run of moderately easy years I will soon be faced with the case $N=80$. I know that there are $52$ such groups but want to "understand" them.

If $|G|=60$, $P\in\operatorname{Syl}_2(G)$, $Q\in\operatorname{Syl}_5(G)$ then we have to deal with the following cases.

(A) $Q\not\lhd G$.  In this case $G$ must be the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$ by a $5$-cycle acting as the companion matrix of $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$.

(B) $Q\lhd G$ and $N(Q)/C(Q)=1$. Here we get the direct products of each of the $14$ groups of order $16$ with $C_5$.

(C) $Q\lhd G$ and $N(Q)/C(Q)\simeq C_2$. Answers to the question posed will let us describe which semidirect products occur.

(D) $Q\lhd G$ and $N(Q)/C(Q)\simeq C_4$. The answer to [Groups of order $16$ with a cyclic quotient of order $4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363319/groups-of-order-16-with-a-cyclic-quotient-of-order-4) by @DerekHolt lets us describe which semidirect products occur.

**My Working**: Using this list https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16 we can see (by considering the Frattini quotient) that we have the following number of subgroups of index 2 for each group.

group 1  :  One (and it is unique)

groups 2-9: Three each (and by looking at isomorphism types there must be at least two classes under the automorphism group)

groups 10-13: Seven each

group 14: Fifteen (but all equivalent under the automorphism group)

(I note that subgroups of index $2$ are normal, so that one only needs to know the action of the outer automorphism group of $P$.)

Comment: I am sure that you will disagree with me, but questions like this are trivial to answer on a computer using GAP or Magma, and  I find it hard to see any reason for attempting to do it by hand, any more than I would see much point in multiplying two 20-digit numbers by hand.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't really disagree, although it can be fun to see how far one can push things "by hand". J A Todd once told me that he'd given up group theory "when it ceased to be a subject for gentlemen" - I didn't sympathise with the viewpoint then, and hope I'm still on the side of "the players" who just get the job done.

Comment: @ancientmathematician It depends. On the one hand, it is useful to do calculations by hand to get more insight. On the other hand, if it becomes too cumbersome and time consuming, it is rather a waste of time. In the case of order $80$, I tend to agree that computers should do it.

Comment: @Peter I do not disagree. But this is unserious coffee machine mathematics, like factorising the date, so waste of time is not relevant.